# Mpdf remove footer and use it's space for content

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

This is my first time using Mpdf.
I want to delete space on the bottom of my pdf layout,
this is the pic of my pdf
[image]

I think this is the space of footer because when I add `<footer></footer>` it can fill the space.
I want to delete the space so my table layout can reach the bottom.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to set margin-bottom & margin-footer. Refer 
https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-top-margins.html

Comment: still the same bro

Answer (score 1):

[Use the @page CSS property](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html) to control the page margins.

```
@page {
   margin: 5mm 10mm 5mm 10mm;
}
```

The order of the units is top, right, bottom, left. That will allow for a bigger content area.